# Falla el reenvio de email para confirmar correo electrónico en registro de laravel

Tags: laravel-6

Tengo un sistema de registro que requiere autenticación del correo electrónico que se ingresó en el registro. La aplicación envía el correo electrónico correctamente con el correspondiente botón que enlaza a la verificación del correo.

También protegí por middleware la ruta de los perfiles para evitar que en el caso que quiera acceder, sin haber verificado su correo. Ahora bien, probé meterme en el perfil del usuario logueado y anda todo perfecto. Sale el mensaje que se ve a continuación:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí se puede ver el link donde el usuario puede solicitar el reenvío del correo electrónico. Ahora cuando hago clic en ese enlace me sale el siguiente error:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé qué hacer, el error apunta a un componente del framework. Pero al mismo tiempo ahí aparece una ruta: http://127.0.0.1:8000/email/resend que no creo tener...

---

Cuando hago php artisan:route list me sale el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
No entiendo porque me pone eso si no tengo esa ruta en los controladores, tengo una carpeta Admin y dentro tengo el HomeController pero dentro de Admin no tengo otra carpeta Admin

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ese enlace al que intentas acceder lo has creado tu o es uno de los incluidos en Auth?

Comment: es el enlace que viene en la vista views/auth/verify.blade.php

Comment: puedes añadir una captura del resultado de ejecutar el comando php artisan route:list en la carpeta de tu proyecto? Gracias

Comment: ahora la agrego

Comment: Has probado a hacer composer dump-autoload?

Comment: probe todo... hasta limpie todos los caches... no se lo que esta pasando busque globalmente en el proyecto para saber si me mande algun use Admin\Admin\HomeController pero no...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103606/discussion-between-mnibor-and-angogi).

Comment: Personalmente tuve muchos problemas con laravel desde la version 5.8 con funcionalidades como json, rutas, facades quiza existan mas pero no quize probarlos mas. te recomiendo bajar la version de tu laravel a 5.6

Comment: uhhhhhhhhhh me muero en 3, 2, 1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema estaba en el archivo verify.blade.php que esta ubicado en views/auth. El link que está en ese archivo hay que reemplazarlo por esto:

```
<form class="d-inline" method="post" action="{{ route('verification.resend') }}">
     @csrf
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2 float-right">
         {{ __('Resend email') }}
     </button>
</form>
```